# About the power series of a function satisfying $f(0)=1$ and $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^na^nf(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

1. Let $f(x)$ be a function with the following properties:

- i. $f(0)=1$
- ii. For all integers $n\ge 0$ , the $n$-th derivative, $f^{\left(n\right)}\left(x\right)=\left(-1\right)^na^nf\left(x\right)$, where $a>0$ & $a\neq 0$.

(a) Write the first four non-zero terms and the general term of the power series of f(x) centered at zero, in terms of a.

- So I attempted this as a "write the Maclaurin series expansion" question from n=0 to n=3 to get four terms. I ended up with: $f\left(x\right)=1-ax+\frac{a^2x^2}{2!}-\frac{a^3x^3}{3!}$. To get this, I used the formula I was given for the "nth derivative" to plug it into the Maclaurin series: $f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)+f'\left(0\right)x+\frac{f''\left(0\right)x^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''\left(0\right)x^3}{3!}$. How would I get the general term?

(b) Write f(x) as a familiar function in terms of a.

- For this, I'm guessing I'll have to figure what the function is based on part a once I solidify my answer for part a.

(c) How many terms of the power are necessary to approximate f(0.2) with an error less than 0.001 with a=2? Justify your answer.

- Depending on whether or not it's an alternating series, then I'll use the Lagrange error bound or the alternating series error bound (but this is also based on part a)?

Also, I'm new, so apologies if I didn't format or follow guidelines.

Comment: Your calculation of $f'(0)$ is baffling.  You are told $f'(0) = (-1)^1 a^1 f(0) = -a \cdot 1 = -a$.

Comment: Your first four term MacLauren series is correct.  You are then expected to look at the terms and guess the pattern for all the rest of the terms to complete a.  For b you are to take the answer from a and recognize the series of a familiar function.  You can use the known properties of that function to prove it solves the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^na^nf(x)$, then $f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^na^n$, and therefore the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is$$1-ax+\frac{a^2}{2!}x^2-\frac{a^3}{3!}x^3+\cdots=e^{-ax}.$$Can you take it from here?